# Missing items when screen size is small

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, muse

I've been trying to fix this issue for a week. I was asked to remove a form from a third party provider which I did, added an email link and it works.

This site was created in Muse by someone else. It's giving me a warning that items are missing. (prior to adding the email link) I can't find those either, as far as I can tell nothing is missing.

I added two columns with responsive code but when I shrink the screen the items disappear.
Here is a link to the page [HeartSongYogaStudio - contactcopy](https://heartsongyogastudio.com/contactcopy.html)

```
enter code here = does not work so I've added a screen shot
```

[image: Code]

...some omitted because it's too long

Comment: Please include the code that isn't working properly in a minimal reproducible example inside your question. The way it's posted right now it's very difficult to answer and you are likely to receive downvotes and no answers.

Comment: To start with, the HTML you added is invalid. Don't put semicolons between attributes.

Comment: This is what I added: <section id="content">
      <div class="middle-content">
         <div class="container">
            
                <div class="row"><!-- first row -->
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- second column -->
                    <div class="widget-item">
                      <h3 class="widget-title">Location</h3>
                      <div class="sample-thumb"> <img src="images/1123170858-crop-u37916.jpg" alt="HeartSong_Yoga_Studio_Class" id="Location" title="HeatSong Yoga Location"> </div>
...sample

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like me to show you for code? Did you go to the link? Do you see the missing warning? If you click ok it shows the page. But my main problem is how the responsive part doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the email link you added. And please edit the question to include your code, don't paste it as a comment.

Comment: Ok. I will add it. The link is to the page, it's not the email link. I think the responsive issue is something in the muse because the section/container/col... work on another site.

Comment: The email link was invalid, which you have now fixed; however it didn't solve the bigger issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues in the CSS:

1: remove `overflow:hidden` on `.widget-item`, because it's overflowing and clipping the content when you squeeze the screen.

2 remove class `.breakpoint` on the top level div, because there's a media query or script somewhere that's removing class `active` on that div at smaller screen widths, resulting in `display:none`. (what's the breakpoint stuff doing?)

*the attached image shows the page rendering more normally with these attributes/classes removed:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! :) I was trying so hard to edit the question to include the things you found! If I could I would hug you right now.

Comment: I have no idea what the breakpoint stuff is doing because I didn't create the page.

Comment: Ok I removed the .breakcode and menu and header of the page get hacked out in a mobile view. So with that I think the break code is something in the menu and pics above menu. Here is the .breakcode: ,.breakpoint{display:none;}#muse_css_mq{position:absolute;display:none;background-color:#FFFFFE;}.fluid_height_spacer{width:0.01px;}.muse_check_css{display:none;position:fixed;}@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){body{text-rendering:auto;}

Comment: And I get this warning: JavaScript exception: Error calling selector function: ReferenceError: suppressMissingFileError is not defined

Comment: Any suggestions on why the center disappears on an iPad and cell phone?

Comment: it's that `.breakpoint` system most likely, which is hiding the first div and then showing one of the other two top-level divs (putting `.active` on them), but those divs appeared empty to me.  I presume this is possibly to show different content entirely for smaller screens?  i'm not really sure